# Xamarin ObjectDisposedException on Webservice Call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm getting a lot of **objectdisposed** exceptions when calling webservices after upgrading to the latest `xamarin.android`. Any ideas?

```
Error: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters)
```

Comment: You're essentially trying to call a method on an object that is no longer there, you have disposed it - meaning you the programmer have explicitly said this object can now be garbage collected. You can't say you're done with it then try and use it again - what are you, some kind of liar? Can you post the code which is throwing the exception?

Comment: It's just calling a method from the generated proxy created by adding a web reference to a soap webservice. The exception is from the internal implementation of the httpwebclientprotocol and there's nothing for me to dispose.

Comment: Can you post the code that makes the actual request?

Comment: `var result = SomeWebservice.Somemethod(userName)`

The SomeWebservice in this case is a static readonly property in a static class that refers to a static variable that is initialized to the proper url (based on a config file) when it is null. Nothing ever disposes of it.

Comment: Ahh see there's your problem. No semicolon at the end! Your welcome.

Comment: I've been facing this issue for a while now. Although using Xamarin Forms. It's apparently very random.

Comment: We managed to resolve this problem by wrapping the httpclient inside a using block